# How can I make mandatory for a derived class to have all basic data-type properties to be of Nullable types?

Tags: c#, nullable

How can I make mandatory for a derived class to have all basic data-type properties to be of Nullable types?

That is, the derived class must have all basic data type properties of nullable types.

Comment: That's none of the base-class's business. So: No.

Answer (score 3):

The is no magic way of doing that, except perhaps via reflection at runtime. In particular, the compiler won't help you do that.

It seems a very unusual requirement - perhaps if you indicate *why* we can help more...

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with standard C#. It's the kind of thing FxCop or NDepend may be able to detect for you... or if all the derived classes will be in a predictable set of assemblies, you could write unit tests to analyze them.